# Lists and loops and changing elements

Tags: python

How would I loop through a list to find if a number is over 9, if any numbers are over 9 then subtract that number by 9.

```
list = [2,2,12,14,18,9]
newlist = [2,2,3,5,9,9]
```

Comment: What have you tried, this is a very basic task. Unless you don't know any programming then I would assume you would have something you tried. Otherwise I would recommend going over a tutorial on Python.

Comment: To be clear, it sounds like you want "21" become "12". If not, you might be describing the "modulus" function. Also, looping through, modifying, and creating arrays are basics in python, so I recommend you read some python guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

> One line solution:

```
list = [2,2,12,14,18,9]
print([i-9 if i>9 else i for i in list ])
```

output:

```
[2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 9]
```

> Detailed Solution:

Above list comprehension is same as :

```
new_list=[]
for item in list:
    if item>9:
        new_list.append(item-9)
    else:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try to implement this into my code

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension or a loop. The first is more "Pythonic"

```
list = [2,2,12,14,18,9]
new_list = [x if x <= 9 else x-9 for x in list]
```

or

```
list = [2,2,12,14,18,9]
new_list = []
for x in list:
    if x <= 9:
        new_list.append(x)
    else:
        new_list.append(x-9)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need something like **modulus**.

```
list = [2, 2, 12, 14, 18, 9]
new_list = [9 if x%9==0 else x%9 for x in list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 9]
```

If you want to subtract 9 once, then use:

```
new_list = [x-9 if x>9 else x for x in list]
```